# How many zero's does a general real entire function $f(z)$ have?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, roots

Let $f(z)$ be a real entire function. How do we find the number of solutions for $f(w)=0$ ?

Can we express the number of zero's of $f$ in terms of its Taylor coëfficiënts ?

Im not looking for the positions of the zero's nor closed form for them.

I just want the amount of zero's for a general real entire function.

Im aware of the Argument Principle, Rouché 's theorem and many other theorems.
But it seems to help little for the general case.

I also wonder; in number theory its often the position of the zero's that matters. 
What is a typical example of when the amount matters more (in number theory) ?

Comment: I think the real analytic case can be very badly behaved. For complex analytic we have [the Weierstrauss factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). In particular, the zeroes can be an arbitrary sequence with no condensation points.

Comment: I am not sure, but Richardson's theorem seems to imply that the number of zeros is even not computable, if ARBITARY entire functions are allowed.

Comment: @Timmy : Im aware of the Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Comment: @Peter : Richardson's theorem is about the reals.
Since that is a line on the complex plane , in many ways that is rather position , then the amount of zero's.
However If such a undecidable problem on the real line has been proven to have no zero's off the real line , then perhaps it is a good example.
But that might require a slightly stronger version of Richardson's theorem ?